# How do you set the executable output location for a Haskell project built with Stack?

Tags: haskell, build, compilation, haskell-stack

While `build`ing my Haskell programs with Stack, I'm trying to get the executable to be written to `project/dist/` but no matter what command line arguments I use or config files I change, it always ends up in `project/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/project/`.

After spending a decent amount of time looking at the command line arguments for the `stack` command, as well as options in `project.cabal`, `Setup.hs`, and `stack.yaml`, I can't seem to find how to configure the output location of `stack build`.

How do you configure the executable output location for `stack build`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `--copy-bins` flag (or the `install` command) to copy the executables to some output directory. That destination directory can be controlled with `--local-bin-path`, but defaults to `~/.local/bin` on POSIX systems.

Comment: code sample, `stack --local-bin-path _build install` => `_build/x-exe` created.

Answer (score 6):

`stack path --local-install-root` outputs path to build artifact. You just need to add `/bin/name-of-my-exe` to this path to get path of executable. And then you just run simple one-line bash script to copy executable to desired location.

Full command for completeness:

```
cp "$(stack path --local-install-root)/bin/name-of-my-exe" ~/.local/bin/name-of-my-exe
```